# $if An \subseteq A $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, $ then $ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty An \subseteq A $

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was given this as an exercise in my discrete math class and I have been having a lot of trouble, I am not really sure how to approach a problem like this. Any help is appreciated!Thank you! (this is my re-edited version)

Let $A1, A2, A3, ... An$ be an infinite sequece of subsets of $\Omega$.

One defines $ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty An$ = {$x \in \Omega |\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, x\in An$}

Heres the actual proof that I am having difficulty with:

$if An \subseteq A $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, $ then $ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty An \subseteq A $

Comment: It's not correct in its current state: Let $A = \emptyset$, for example (less trivial counterexamples are easy to construct too).

Comment: If $a\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, then $a\in A_i$ for some $i\in\mathbb N$. By assumption, $a\in A_i\subset A$, so $a\in A$. That should be a sufficient proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of starting with the most complex side, expanding the definitions, and then applying the rules of predicate logic working towards the other side.

Using a slightly different notation, and implicitly letting $\;n\;$ range over ${\mathbb N}^+$, we can calculate

\begin{align}
& \langle \cup n :: A_n \rangle \;\subseteq\; A \\
= & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in \langle \cup n :: A_n \rangle \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \rangle \\
= & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\langle \cup \ldots \rangle\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \exists n :: x \in A_n \rangle \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \rangle \\
= & \qquad \text{"logic: use (0) below, allowed since $\;x \in A\;$ does not contain $\;n\;$} \\
  & \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{-- to get $\;A\;$ closer to $\;A_n\;$, as in our goal"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \forall n :: x \in A_n \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \rangle \rangle \\
= & \qquad \text{"logic: exchange quantifiers} \\
  & \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{-- to bring $\;n\;$ to the outside, as in our goal"} \\
& \langle \forall n :: \langle \forall x :: x \in A_n \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \rangle \rangle \\
= & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall n :: A_n \;\subseteq\; A \rangle \\
\end{align}
which actually shows that $\;\langle \cup n :: A_n \rangle \;\subseteq\; A\;$ and $\;\langle \forall n :: A_n \;\subseteq\; A \rangle\;$ are equivalent.

Here I used the following rule of predicate logic:
$$
(\langle \exists z :: P(z) \rangle \Rightarrow Q) \;\equiv\; \langle \forall z :: P(z) \Rightarrow Q \rangle \tag{0}
$$
where $\;Q\;$ does not contain $\;z\;$.  Here is more detail on that rule (which I keep reinventing because I cannot remember it):
\begin{align}
& \langle \exists z :: P(z) \rangle \Rightarrow Q \\
= & \qquad \text{"write $\;p \Rightarrow q\;$ as $\;\lnot p \lor q\;$"} \\
& \lnot \langle \exists z :: P(z) \rangle \lor Q \\
= & \qquad \text{"DeMorgan"} \\
& \langle \forall z :: \lnot P(z) \rangle \lor Q \\
= & \qquad \text{"bring $\;\lor Q\;$ into quantification, using $\;Q\;$ does not contain $\;z\;$} \\
  & \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{-- this rule I }\textit{can}\text{ remember"} \\
& \langle \forall z :: \lnot P(z) \lor Q \rangle \\
= & \qquad \text{"write $\;\lnot p \lor q\;$ as $\;p \rightarrow q\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall z :: P(z) \Rightarrow Q \rangle \\
\end{align}